# Recyclerview lags when accessing position from its adapter

Tags: android

I am looking to do one-time job which is obtaining the first three objects from my custom list in my adapter & do some logic with it, thus i am accessing ***position*** from OnBindViewHolder

But when i do access it and do my logic, it produces major lag into my recyclerview especially when am scrolling

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.mGoldTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (position == 1) {
    holder.mSilverTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (position == 2) {
    holder.mBronzeTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

When i remove this code, it runs smoothly

Edit: I tried to remove position & setting visibility right away, it caused lag as well, so i thought it would be problem with my layout

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/ID_image_upload_photoOfTheUser"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/hey"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000" />

                <!--It can be 30dp & 36dp-->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ID_my_talent_golden_trophy"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/golden_trophy"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ID_my_talent_silver_trophy"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/silver_trophy"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ID_my_talent_bronze_trophy"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/bronze_trophy"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try to separate these checks because these checks are different for different views means to put a different check on different view i.e.  holder.mTrophy.setVisibiliity(position==desiredposition?View.Visible:View.Gone)

Comment: try to handle all the cases in viewholders both for true and false. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I'll do what you suggest tomorrow, got a bit of inquiry here, what is this syntax: position==desiredposition?View.Visible:View.Gone

I never used it, does it has a name so i can google about it ?

Comment: this is not any specific method its just a ifelse condition using operators. I just told you to handle all the cases both positive or negative for all your views like gold/silver/bronze trophies. You can use ifelse also for your understanding

Comment: Thanks, but i found that the problem wasn't in getting position but it was from my layout file(i guess), so i posted my layout above, is there something wrong with it, as it's my first time to use FrameLayout

Comment: seems like image resolution was large and i forgot to resize it, thanks for helping tho <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code, the problem was with the image, i used a very large image without resizing it, thus it showed much lag when i used it.

Solution would be changing the size of my drawable  into smaller sizes

I used [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit) to fix up this error, and it works fine with smooth motion, Thanks for your time.